# Python Fabric: Trying to distribute different files to hosts

Tags: python, fabric

Is there a way to specify what file will be put to host when using Fabric?

I have a list of hosts with platform specified, such as:

```
host_list = [['1.1.1.1', 'centos5_x64'], ['2.2.2.2','centos6_x86']]
```

I want to write something like:

```
from fabric.api import env, execute

env.hosts = [x[0] for x in hosts_list]

def copy()
    put('some_rpm' + <platform>)

execute(copy)
```

So how can I specify the platform string for each host in env.hosts?

All other steps in my Fabric-based install & test script are equal for each host,
so the obvious answer is to write a 'threaded_copy()' that will do the job. But still, a Fabric-based solution should be much clearer...

Answer (score 0):

As always, I've found the answer myself a while after posting the question here :)

```
def copy()
    platform_string = get_platform_for_host(env.host)
    put('some_rpm' + platform_string)
```

The **env.host** variable will hold the current host the function is executing on (tested... works).